# How to use knockout.js with CMS?

Tags: javascript, forms, data-binding, knockout.js, content-management-system

All the examples at ko.js site are build manually and models and views are handcrafted.

What if I want to use ko.js on site that doesn't create data-binding attributes in the backend? Is it possible to apply bindings dynamically in document?

Otherwise it seems like ko.js would support only custom projects and not e.g. CMS sites such as WordPress or Drupal (without extensive customization).

Say I have a nice form rendered from CMS that I would like to use together with ko.js to provide functionality. How do I add ko.js to it?

Comment: KnockoutJS is perfectly suitable for CMS'es if the CMS is 'flexible' enough. As an example, I wrote [KO Site Settings](http://get-simple.info/extend/plugin/ko-site-settings/913/) plugin for (static/ no DB) [GetSimple CMS](http://get-simple.info). Given that all CMS'es support hooks (I think?), and if 1) you know some PHP (and SQL if required) to configure how the KO data is sent/ saved (in my plugin I send data to a PHP script with AJAX), and 2) you are able to include the Knockout library in the backend, you're all set.

Comment: Interesting. I've used GetSimple in few of my projects. How do you take advantage of KO in GS? Or how would you use it in a site? In-place/Live-edit? Is there other modules that depend on this ko module?

Comment: Well I'm currently completely overhauling it because v0.1 was kind of a test 'draft', so not very readable code. The setting list on [this screenshot from the version I'm working on](http://i.imgur.com/FkpySdM.png) is an observableArray; so I'm using it to provide a very responsive UI in the backend. KO allows me to handle almost everything client-side (AJAX data sending; HTML instead of PHP templates & json data save/retrieval)

Comment: If you want to do live-site editing however, you're gonna have to pre-render the page conditionally (if the user is logged into backend)  and add ko bindings to it, then initialize it (which might prove to be a very hard task). If you're looking for a pure JS view implementation separated from the HTML, you might be more interested in [React.js](http://facebook.github.io/react/) (easier to simply include a JS file if user is logged in).

Comment: But to get back to my original question that was about adding data-bind attributes on-the-fly. Found one article about it: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/138654/Client-side-Model-Binding-using-ASP-NET-MVC-jQuery In that article javascript calls for custom setupbindings function that adds ko.js data-binding attributes and after that it calls  for applybindings. It is a bit backwards climbing but is it a total no-no or plausible method? (as an quick'n'dirty method).

Answer (score 2):

From what I can ascertain from your description, I don't think knockout or indeed any MVVM binding framework is correct for you. It would be good to understand more about what you are trying to do, with some sample code, before we help any further.

The samples over at knockout's page are a little simple, you may want to check out http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2014/07/30/spa-angular-knockout.html for a more in-depth article with code.

Comment: Hi! Thanks. What I'm looking for is to have a form element dependency e.g. this is checked than that disabled or if checked count X than disabled these checkboxes. In short to able to count checked values, change UI according to it and to perhaps some input validation too. I made it with jQuery but it became such a spaghetti.

As an example I could refer to jQuery DataTables plugin html table: just include it and BOOM you've got a amazing table to play with. (Though ko.js requires programming but to give perspective of that you have your markup which you would like to bring to life)